# Hello World Example of a Digital Waveguide in JavaScript

Tags: wave, programming

*I am just learning about sound so might be jumping the gun a bit. But it helps me stay motivated and get into an interesting problem to solve to ask these more complicated questions.*

I am looking at [Digital Waveguides](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/pasp/Digital_Waveguide_Theory.html), and would like to know how to implement them practically in JavaScript. I am new to all these concepts so have done some basic stuff with oscillators and played with Tone.js, but I am not familiar yet with *how and where* "digital waveguides" would be implemented in the Browser API situation.

I saw the [Sound Synthesis Toolkit in C++](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/index.html), and they have a class in there called `Mesh2D`. I'm not sure if that means Digital Waveguide 2D Mesh or what, but it looks like it's getting close to a hello world example with code snippets like this:

```
StkFloat Mesh2D :: energy( void )
{
  // Return total energy contained in wave variables Note that some
  // energy is also contained in any filter delay elements.

  int x, y;
  StkFloat t;
  StkFloat e = 0;
  if ( counter_ & 1 ) { // Ready for Mesh2D::tick1() to be called.
    for ( x=0; x<NX_; x++ ) {
      for ( y=0; y<NY_; y++ ) {
        t = vxp1_[x][y];
        e += t*t;
        t = vxm1_[x][y];
        e += t*t;
        t = vyp1_[x][y];
        e += t*t;
        t = vym1_[x][y];
        e += t*t;
      }
    }
  }
  else { // Ready for Mesh2D::tick0() to be called.
    for ( x=0; x<NX_; x++ ) {
      for ( y=0; y<NY_; y++ ) {
        t = vxp_[x][y];
        e += t*t;
        t = vxm_[x][y];
        e += t*t;
        t = vyp_[x][y];
        e += t*t;
        t = vym_[x][y];
        e += t*t;
      }
    }
  }

  return e;
}
```

My question is, how do I implement this "Discrete simulation of the ideal, lossy waveguide" in JavaScript?

[image: https://www.dsprelated.com/josimages_new/pasp/img3343.png]

They say "sampling these exponentially traveling waves, etc.", and provide this sampling equation:

[image: https://www.dsprelated.com/josimages_new/pasp/img3339.png]

How do I connect these "dots" into a function that produces a sound on click, using this digital waveguide system? This would help introduce me into the world of *implementation* of the theoretical sound stuff, as well as the more advanced sound generation concepts. I am mainly confused what the data is supposed to be and how to map it to an actual sound in JavaScript.

Some related links:

- https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/pasp/Digital_Waveguide_Oscillator.html
- [https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pmudw/](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/pmudw/)